# slice an array by specific way

Tags: ruby

There is a good slice method in Python like

```
my_array[3:]
```

I'm aware there are slice methods in Ruby as well, but there is no method which does exactly the same as Python's `my_array[3:]` (in case if don't know the size of the array). Is not it?

Comment: I think you could do `my_array[3..-1]`. It's just a translation of `my_array[3:-1]`.

Comment: It might help if you told us what that python code does.

Comment: It returns all the elements starting with the 3rd one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Array
    def sub_array(pos, len = -1)
        if len == -1
        then # the rest of the array starting at pos
            len = self.size - pos
        end
        self.slice(pos, len)
    end
end

my_array = %w[a b c d e f]
p my_array.sub_array(3)     #=> ["d", "e", "f"]
p my_array.sub_array(5)     #=> ["f"]
p my_array.sub_array(9)     #=> nil
p my_array.sub_array(3, 2)  #=> ["d", "e"]
p my_array.sub_array(3, 9)  #=> ["d", "e", "f"]
```

Actually this was originally a substring method for String.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the ruby [slice methods](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-slice) here. and as @Blender suggested you can pass a range like:

```
my_array[3..-1]
```

EDIT:

## range example

```
array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
array[3..-1]
```

will result in `["d", "e"]` as `d`'s index is 3 and `e` is the last element.

## more examples

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ]
a[2] +  a[0] + a[1]    #=> "cab"
a[6]                   #=> nil
a[1, 2]                #=> [ "b", "c" ]
a[1..3]                #=> [ "b", "c", "d" ]
a[4..7]                #=> [ "e" ]
a[6..10]               #=> nil
a[-3, 3]               #=> [ "c", "d", "e" ]
# special cases
a[5]                   #=> nil
a[5, 1]                #=> []
a[5..10]               #=> []
```

Comment: What does it do? I can't find the example in the documentation.

Comment: see the updated answer with an example. providing a range will return a new array using the elements within that range.

Comment: I meant, there is no example in the documentation.

Comment: There are a few examples in the image provided i guess.

Comment: just follow this link http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-slice

Comment: So what of it? There is no example of [any_number.. negative_number].

Comment: i am not sure why you are not able to view the examples, i have updated the answer with examples copied from the mentioned link.

Comment: There is no example of [any_number.. negative_number]

Comment: why are you looking for a specific example ? why not try it yourself ?